# More efficient way to do multi-label classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

Let's say you have a regular multi-class classification of whether an image contains a dog, a cat, or a bird. This is a relatively trivial (given enough data) to solve.

If you wanted to have a combination of a dog, a cat or a bird in a single image, this would be a multi-label problem.

For a small number of possible individual elements, this seems easy to create a dataset containing all possible combinations and teach a NN to recognize combinations. But what if you have a large dataset of perhaps 50 possible animals and upwards of 5 in a single image?

At that point there would be far too many combinations, not even taking into account the fact that each combination needs multiple images.

Is there a way for a NN to learn, perhaps, to just recognize each individual animal, but then learn how to recognize multiple animals, given that it knows how to identify one?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut I mean I already selected the right answer and nobody has posted anything new, so closing the question would be a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, but 1) anyone else can still answer (you will be surprized by how many people chose to add new answers in years-old questions) and 2) leaving such questions open sets up an undesired precedent, as people with similar off-topic questions can point here and claim "*look, why you close my question - this is similar*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could just train 50 NNs, one for each animal.

But generally in a single network you would use softmax as a last layer in a neural network when there is only one animal per image.

In the case you described you can just replace that last softmax (e.g. by a dense layer with sigmoid activation function) to make your network able to predict the probability for every animal independently.

Comment: But the issue then becomes that there would (in this case) 50^5 possible combinations, not taking into account that each combination needs multiple specific images for the neural network to be trained on.

Comment: But you do not need multiple examples for each combination. Your network should not learn each combination, it should learn that if there is a cat in the image the first neuron in the last layer is 1. That means you neeed multiple pictures with a cat and multiple with a dog, but not neccessarily pictures with a cat and a dog. Anyway train 50 individual networks is a less complex problem thus less data needed for "good" results.